# Magento 1.9.0.1 Image Size

Tags: image, magento, image-size

I am using Magento 1.9.0.1.

When I go on a Category to view the products, All products are shown in square boxes. 
As my images are rectangle, I can see the white space on left and right sides of the images.

Please advise how to edit the code so that images are shown rectangle shape (hight:300px width:200px).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code for product images in list.phtml file(`app/design/frontend/[current package]/[current theme]/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`)

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepFrame(false)->resize($width, $height); ?>
```

Hope this helps! Thanks.

Comment: However this has changed the image sizes on the category page only. When I look at NEW PRODUCTS section at homepage the image boxes are still square and not changed. Could you please advise why is that and how can I changed those images as well as well.  Thanks

Comment: Actually I found where to put the code you advised. You are a star

Answer (score 4):

Take a look @

> /app/design/frontend/default/{theme}/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

Change `resize(width, height)`

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(158, 150); ?>
```

Comment: Hi, I pretend the same thing. but size doesn't changed. image source looking like/product/cache/7/small_image/240x318/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/i/m/img14.jpg. but while on hover those image its still shows width as 218. what can i do??

Comment: Do you have any type of page cache enable?

Comment: Nopes, i didn't enable anything. what i expect for is product images should be in width 240px and height 318px.